# Multi-Org API User

Tags: marketing-cloud

One question I haven't been able to nail down through documentation is if we need to set up one unique Marketing Cloud API User and Salesforce system user per BU?

Comment: What kind of setup exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Multi-Org setup with multiple Sales Clouds (different brands) feeding into their own brand business units for a 1:1 connection. Defining if I need multiple API Users per BU or 1 overarching for all connections. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you are connecting multiple BUs with multiple Salesforce orgs, use separate API users on both sides:

> Use dedicated API users. Assign each connected business unit a
>   dedicated API user to reduce confusion after connecting. If multiple
>   business units are connected to the same Salesforce org, use a shared
>   API User.

Source: [Multi-Org Account Configuration](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_multi_org_account_configuration.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null)

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was missing.